# NPM - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\'

Tags: node.js, npm

New to nodejs and npm. I have installed nodejs and npm using nvm for windows. Now no matter what library I try to install I get:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-03T16_56_40_199Z-debug.log
```

I've tried clearing the cache, changing the install path, setting the prefix at both the command line and in the config file. Any more suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen if you run CMD through administrator?

Comment: Yes, I have admin rights and am running in an admin cmd.

Comment: Did you clean the cache like this:  `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: Yep, multiple times.

Comment: So after trying a number of different things I ended up uninstalling NVM for Windows and reinstalling straight nodejs/NPM from the NPM site and it works fine.